# Form submission using ajax and page view moderation after the submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-4

At this moment I am using laravel. In this context I am having a form which is successfully submitted by using ajax to a controller. and that controller make it to the database. But the problem is as the ajax is doing its job the whole page remain unmoved / unchanged after the submission even the database is updated.

Now what I want

I want to give feedback to the user that your post is successfully submitted there. or what I want to do in further, I want to refresh the section in which the post is collected from the database as this post can be retrieved from there. But by using ajax only.

So there is no need to collect the whole page or refresh.

here is my form structure

`

```
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => array('questions.store'), 'class' => 'form-horizontal'  )) }}

    blah blah blaaa .......


    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $(".form-horizontal").submit(function(e){
                        $(this).unbind("submit")
                        $("#ask").attr("disabled", "disabled")


                        var that = $(this),
                            url = that.attr('action'),
                            type = that.attr('method'),
                            data = {};
                        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
                                var that = $(this),
                                name = that.attr('name'),
                                value = that.val();

                                data[name] = value;

                        });

                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: type,
                            data: data,
                            success: function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                            }
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
                    </script>


{{ Form::close() }}
```

`
 As it is very much visible that the post is updated through a route & controller I want to have another dive and a success message at this script to be displayed after the success of posting. I am looking for some professional structure using what there is minimal need to have interaction with the server side and give user a better page viewing experience.

Thanks a lot for helping me in this research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you well, but if you want to notify the user about the result of an ajax-called db update you need to have

1. a route for the ajax save db call - it should point to a method that does the db update.
2. the db update method should return some value indicating the success/failure of update (for example OK or FAIL)
3. the only result of calling the method will be just plain text page with OK or FAIL as body
4. fetch the result by ajax and inform user accordingly (after form submit button)

check out the below code for ajax call itself (inside the form submit handler) to see what I mean

```
    var db_ajax_handler = "URL_TO_YOUR_SITE_AND_ROUTE";

    var $id = 1; //some id of post to update
    var $content = "blablabla"  //the cotent to update

        $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                timeout: 10000,
                type: 'POST',
                tryCount : 0,
                retryLimit : 3,
                url: db_ajax_handler,
                data: { content: $content, id: $id }, /* best to give a CSRF security token here as well */ 
                beforeSend:function(){

                },
                success:function(data, textStatus, xhr){

                     if(data == "OK") 
                     {
                        $('div.result').html('The new Question has been created');
                     }
                     else
                     {
                       $('div.result').html('Sorry, the new Question has not been created');  
                     }


                },
                error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                        this.tryCount++;
                        if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                            //try again
                            $.ajax(this);
                            return;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    if (xhr.status == 500) {
                        alert("Error 500: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);

                    } else {
                        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);

                    }
                },
                complete : function(xhr, textStatus) {

                }
            });
```

EDIT: as per comment, in step 2 (the method that is called with AJAX) replace

```
if($s) 
{ 
    return Redirect::route('questions.index') ->with('flash', 'The new Question has been created'); 
}
```

with

```
return ($s) ? Response::make("OK") : Response::make("FAIL");
```

**EDIT 2:**
To pass validation errors to the ajax-returned-results, you cannot use

```
return Response::make("FAIL")
        ->withInput()
    ->withErrors($s->errors());
```

as in your GIST. Instead you have to modify the suggested solution to work on JSON response instead of a plain text OK/FAIL. That way you can include the errors in the response and still benefit from the AJAX call (not having to refresh the page to retrieve the $errors from session). Check [this post](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=43195) on the Laravel Forum for a working solution - you will get the idea and be able to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply bro. after submitting the form I need to refresh a div by calling a controller where the data will be generated. now what will be the good way to generate a refresh to that div after that submission ?

Comment: I edited the source as per your comment - just update some div with class='result' with descriptive message :)

Comment: brother can you help me with return success message. I do not know how to return to this ajax method from controller.

before implementing to ajax it was like this ...

`if($s)
    {
     
     
    return Redirect::route('questions.index')
    ->with('flash', 'The new Question has been created');

   }`

Comment: instead of redirecting the user, just return the OK or FAIL message to be fetched by the ajax call. Replace "if($s) { return Redirect:: ... part" with " return ($s) ? Response::make("OK") : Response::make("FAIL");" - this is done in step 2 of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I clicked it as a right answer ( for your unconditional help ). though I may need your help further in this as it is not yet done from my side. So pls reply if I knock here . Thanks brother.

Comment: Brother here in this gist can you pls tell me how to modify this ajax and controller to get the error field of the form working ? I mean the 
`<div class="err control-group{{ $errors->first('about', ' has-error') }}">` is not working after the use of this code.

Gist -> [click me](https://gist.github.com/beingsagir/e240efdc561e8125d0ed)

Comment: OK I see the issue, I will edit my answer but you should put the links to the GISTs in you OP as well, please edit it.

Comment: Op means ? 

Brother what I actually want ? I want to show the error generated through the cntroller which can be a array as well and also I need to pass it to the error div of the form where it makes the textarea red bordered. How can It be achieved ?

Comment: check my edit to get the idea how to change your code from GIST